# How to share data in nested components?

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

I have a sample implementation of nested components(Laravel) with Alpine.js. The problem is, it cannot recognize the child data. It throws a console error below. It seems it won't work having two or more `alpine:init` at one page. But removing one `alpine:init` would cause an error as well.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: input is not defined

**login.blade.php**

```
<div x-data="login">
    <x-input><x-input/>
</div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
        Alpine.data('login', () => ({
            user: 'John'
        }))
    })
</script>
```

**input.blade.php**

```
<div x-data="input">
    <input x-init="console.log('log', inputValue)" />
<div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
        Alpine.data('input', () => ({
            inputValue: 'something'
        }))
    })
</script>
```

---

Does anyone knows how to properly execute this? I have tried searching for existing implementation from github, but I can't find a solid one.

Answer (score 0):

Your execution looks correct, so my guess is that Alpine is loading in the wrong spot and initializing before your definition of `input` is parsed.

Make sure your Alpine script tag is only included once, after the DOM has loaded completely (i.e by adding `defer` to the script tag or by placing it at the bottom of `<body>`)